# Arrayの要素であるArrayは参照型ではないのですか？

Tags: swift, xcode

```
var itemsArray = [[Item]]()
```

と定義して、

```
let items = itemsArray.last
items.removeLast()
let item = newItemWithImage(image as! UIImage)
items.append(item!)
print(itemsArray.last) //反映されない
```

とすると、`itemsArray`の要素に追加したitemが`itemsArray`に反映されません。

代わりに、

```
let items = itemsArray.last
items.removeLast()
item = newItem(image as! UIImage)
itemsArray.removeLast
itemsArray.append(items) //挿入しなおす
print(itemsArray.last) //反映される
```

とすると反映されます。

Arrayの要素であるArrayは「参照型ではない」と理解して良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Arrayの要素であるArrayは「参照型ではない」と理解して良いのでしょうか？*
はい。もう少し言うと、Arrayの要素であるかどうかにかかわらず、Arrayは参照型ではありません。

さらに若干補足しておくと、SwiftのArrayは、内部表現的には`NSArray`やそれに似た何かへの参照を保持していることもありますが、たとえ多重配列になった場合でも「値型」として振る舞うように巧妙にwrapされています。

Swift3では、さらにObjective-Cのデータ型(参照型)からブリッジされる値型が多数導入されます。(NSDataに対応するData型など。)それらも、たとえArrayの要素になっていても、値型として振る舞います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。Arrayの要素は、画面遷移の時などに渡して、そのままプロパティとか変更した後に、Arrayに挿入しなおさなくても、変更が反映されているので、参照型として使っていました。

Arrayは「参照を保持する場合」と「値型」として振る舞う場合があるのですね。

Comment: そうですね。その場合、Arrayそのものは「値型」だが、「要素が参照型」という状態です。ほとんど中身の同じclass(参照型)とstruct(値型)を定義してみて、それぞれのArrayの振る舞いがどうなるか確かめてみると「参照型を保持する場合」「値型を保持する場合」の違いがわかるかと思います。

Comment: なるほど上の場合「Item」はclassとして定義しているので、参照になっているんですね！勉強になります。structは値型なんですね。structでやるとどうなるか試してみます。